# Adding userform to top readingpane

Tags: vba, outlook, userform

Let me begin by saying i am no expert in VBA what so ever. I tinker around with it since yesterday...

Our company recently switched to Office 2016, Yay!
The only issue we have is that we cant directly modify subjects from the reading pane in outlook anymore. (We store handler data there)

This can be resolved by eighter opening the whole email, expanding the headers and editing the subject...

This is tiresome, so i've made a VBA script to edit the headers instead. 
It works fine when i input it as a macro on the ribbon but it misses a certain feature.

I've created an userform that allows the user to fill in his employee number and input his remarks.
Here's the issue; i need the userform to always display near the email, preferribly on top of the reading pane.

If i put it in the ribbon the userform will display (on click) but that requires three button presses instead of just one.

I've seen this kind of system before, so i know its possible. I just have no clue how.

tl;dr
How do i add a userform to the position(s) located in the image.

Edit1: Extra info: 
I know how to call the UserForm. I want to hook it on the locations stated on the picture. (On load with outlook, as an "extra menu" ~ ish

[Outlook location / userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doFhN.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a task pane, where you can put any controls. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338197(v=office.12).aspx for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to go to the macro of worksheet and add this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
     UserForme1.show
End Sub
```

It will automatically display your userforme when you open the worksheet.

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but I hope i can help.

Comment: Isn't Worksheet_SelectionChange an excel thing? (It doesnt seem to work in outlook)